# Format Changing Problem of Number Input in streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

The program offers the number format as Default in a.b format (like 1.2)  but I want to show as a:b format (like 1:2)
How can I change this? I tried below but it didn’t work:

```
(st.number_input(“time”)).replace(".",":")
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str(st.number_input(“time”,format="%f")).replace(".",":")
```